# Ruby on Rails adding double quotes to "find" function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle10g, double-quotes, legacy-database

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I'm having an issue with the find function.

I created a new web app which connects to a legacy Oracle database using the oracle enhanced adapter gem.

When I run the following commands in the rails console, I get data back from the database

```
License.where(license_no: 'L1234')
```

or

```
License.find_by_license_no('L1234')
```

However, when I try to used the find() function, I get an error. i.e.

```
License.find(:all)
```

or
    `License.all`

The error output in the rails console is as follows:

```
irb(main):003:0> License.find(:all)
  ?[1m?[35mLicense Load (1062.5ms)?[0m  SELECT "LICENSE".* FROM "LICENSE"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-01878: specified field not found i
n datetime or interval: SELECT "LICENSE".* FROM "LICENSE"
        from stmt.c:289:in oci8lib_191.so
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-o
racle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanc
ed_oci_connection.rb:155:in `fetch'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-o
racle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanc
ed_adapter.rb:637:in `block in exec_query'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in
log'
```

Looking at the SQL command within the error output, I noticed that double quotes are being added to the select statement. When I tried running the SQL command in SQL Developer, I got an error. Is there any reason why the double quotes are being added? Is there a way to stop ruby on rails from adding the double quotes to the table names?

**UPDATE** The oracle database is 10g and I'm using rails 3.2 with ruby 1.9.2p290. I've also tried the following and got the same error.
`License.all`

Comment: You neglected to mention any of you software versions. So it's hard to be helpful. All we know is that you're dealing with ad old version of DB...

Comment: It appears that the solution to resolve my issue was to update the timezone setting in my /config/initializers/oracle.rb file to match the same timezone as the Oracle database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formatting for using the find function (depending on what version of Rails you're using) in Rails 3, is:

```
License.where('license_no = ?', 'L1234')
```

or

```
License.all
```

to find all of them.

If you are in Rails 2, the formatting would be:

```
License.find(:all, :conditions =>  ["license_no = ?", "L1234"])
```

Look at the **Dynamic Attribute-Based Finders** section here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.2.

I have no issues getting data back from the database when a condition/where clause is implemented, I'm only getting the issue when I try retrieving all the data from the database.

I've tried both:
`License.all` or
`License.find(:all)` and still get the same error in my question.

Comment: It looks like that error is occurring due to a datetime field of sorts in the table. It's an Oracle-specific error. Make sure that the datetime format that Rails is saving into the DB is compatible / correct for the schema you have for those columns in Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the help @StephRose. It appears that the solution to resolve my issue was to update the timezone setting in my /config/initializers/oracle.rb file to match the same timezone as the Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

`Model.find` doesn't accept hash as a first parameter. So it treats your hash (`license_no: 'L1234'`) in a wrong way.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find